# Convert Mix Data Type to Numerical in Python

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I am trying to convert the below table from a mixed data type to numeric

| Stakeholder | Product (CWS) | Credit Related |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Partner Care | Webroot | BR-1278 |
| NOC - PST | RMM - Scripting Inquiry | BR-1460 |

I tried to use the below code

'datac['Stakeholder'] = pd.to_numeric(datac['Stakeholder'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')'

and output is converting the column into blank cells and 0 in few.

Comment: I have tried to use 

'datac['Stakeholder'] = pd.to_numeric(datac['Stakeholder'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')'  

but the output seems incorrect.

I apologize if this is not the correct way to put the code in comment

Comment: pls include your attempted code and output in the question

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. The column "Stakeholder" only contains strings. Why do you want to convert it to int? What is your expected output? Are there only two different stakeholder and one of them should be assigned a `1` and the other a `0`?

Comment: @FredMaster there are more stakeholders, products, I just added 2 of them as an example and I am trying to convert all columns to numerical. 

is it possible to attach the data exel file here

Comment: But based on which logic do you want to convert it to 0s and 1s? Is e.g. "Partner Care" supposed to be assigned a 1 or a 0?

Comment: Are there any numbers in column "Stakeholder"?

Comment: @FredMaster correct 0,1, 2, 3 ..... no numbers in  stakeholders, products except for Credit related

Comment: See my answer. Is this something that helps you?

Comment: @FredMaster i first tried label encoder but that did not work 

'from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()

datac = le.fit_transform(datac)'

Got this - ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (25953, 7) instead.

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: @FredMaster I did not realize that the column has an integer value in the stakeholder column "NOC - R1 Soft" there are only 3 rows for the same

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you want to do.

The problem is that you cannot convert an arbitrary string into int using `astype` because it is unclear to what e.g. "abc" should be converted.

**Conversion to `0` and `1`**

But you could use `try` to check if conversion is possible. If not: you assing a `0`

Something like this:

```
def convert_to_int(col):
    numbers = []
    for el in col:
        try:
            int(el) # Check if conversion to int is possible
            number = 1 # assign 1 if conversion successful 
        except:
            number = 0 # else: assign a 0
        numbers.append(number)
    return numbers

# Example data
data = {"Stakeholder":["Partner Care", "NOC - PST", "12", "0", "Other Stakeholder"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convered df
df["Stakeholder_ints"] = convert_to_int(df["Stakeholder"])
```

**Conversion to numerical categories**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder  
data = {"Stakeholder":["Partner Care", "NOC - PST", "12", "0", "Other Stakeholder"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

col = df["Stakeholder"]
le = LabelEncoder()
df["Stakeholder_cats"] = le.fit_transform(col)
```

Comment: I will try this for sure, unfortunately, I cannot try it now I will get back to you with the output by Saturday.....thank you for the quick response. I wish I could a upvote or thumbs up for for your quick help

Comment: I did not realize that the column has an integer value in the stakeholder column "NOC - R1 Soft"